# Prove 3 diophantine expressions cannot simultaneously be perfect squares

Tags: diophantine-equations

Given s and g are positive integers and $cos\theta$ and $sin\theta$ are rational and not equal to 0 or 1. Show these 3 expressions cannot all be perfect squares:

$$s^2+2g^2-2sg(cos\theta-sin\theta)$$
$$s^2+g^2-2sg(cos\theta)$$
$$s^2+g^2+2sg(sin\theta)$$

Appreciate any tips.

Comment: Trigonometric functions - much in the way to solve the equation. Also not clear - are they independent or not?  So it's best to write more formally using algebraic functions.

Comment: 2 and 3 the equation is dependent from each other.  This means this formulation to solve the problem is not correct. In this case, the number of decisions can be assured.